# System.Net.Http in net47

Tags: c#, .net, target-framework

I have a normal class library on Windows, using .NET 4.7

I would like to include [web-push-csharp](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp).

The package lists 2 acceptable dependencies (Newtonsoft Json and BouncyCastle). It also wants to install [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/). And I have no idea why. I don't need it. My target framework comes with a perfectly fine `System.Net.Http` to reference. **As that Microsoft package has a list of other dependencies that clash with other dependencies higher up in my chain, this is a huge inconvenience. Why would I include a package I don't need?**

Now I thought that that should not be a problem, went and cloned the web push package repository, to put my target framework in and... it's correct, you cannot compile for target framework `net47` without an outside `*.Net.Http` reference. Yet my `Create New Project` .NET 4.7 project already comes with such a reference without touching nuget at all.

Copying all the packages files into a new ClassLibrary1 works great with just NewtonsoftJson and BouncyCastle.

What am I missing here? Why did the .NET Framework lose it's System.Net.Http from 4.5 to 4.6? And why is there no FrameworkTarget available where I can say "this is fine, I have a full 4.7"?

Is there another option aside from just cloning the repository and creating a normal 4.7 class library from it for my use?

---

Additional information:

I cloned the web-push-csharp repository and added a new target framework `net47` without any dependency on `Microsoft.Net.Http`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp1.1;netstandard1.3;net45;net46;net47</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net45' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net46'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.1" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http" Version="2.2.29" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net47'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.1' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.3'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.NetCore" Version="1.8.1.3" /> 
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

That lead to multiple compile errors along the line of:

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) WebPush(net47)

---

## Solution

For anyone reading this looking for a solution: After testing, I incorporated the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790546/system-net-http-in-net47/46791790#46791790) into a [branch](https://github.com/nielsvoigt/web-push-csharp/tree/SystemHttp) of a fork and sent the maintainer a [Pull request](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp/pull/18) so it can be used in the original package.

Comment: Is it really related to .net 4.7? I think you cannot compile that project if you remove dependency on that package even for net45 and net46?

Comment: @Evk hm, true it won't work for the others either, I'll remove that tag.

Comment: Remove that `PackageReference`, add `<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />` (regular, non-nuget reference) and it will compile for both 4.5\6 and 4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the .NET Framework (all mentioned versions: 4.5, 4.6, 4.7) comes with `System.Net.Http` assembly ready to use, so there is no need to reference any nuget packages. But you need to reference this assembly itself:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp1.1;netstandard1.3;net45;net46;net47</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net45' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net46'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.1" /> 
    <!-- here -->
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net47'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.1" />
    <!-- and here -->
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.1' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.3'">
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.NetCore" Version="1.8.1.3" /> 
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the nuspec file, they didnt mention to support .NET 4.7 (https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp/blob/master/WebPush.nuspec) Possibly you can take a clone of the repository and add the modify the file as the below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>WebPush</id>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
    <authors>Cory Thompson</authors>
    <owners>Cory Thompson</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/coryjthompson/web-push-csharp/blob/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/coryjthompson/web-push-csharp/</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Web Push library for C#</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>web push notifications vapid</tags>
    <dependencies>  
        <group targetFramework="netcoreapp1.0">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCore" version="1.8.1.3"/>
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>
        <group targetFramework="netcoreapp1.1">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCore" version="1.8.1.3"/>
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>
        <group targetFramework="netstandard1.3">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCore" version="1.8.1.3"/>
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>

        <group targetFramework="net45">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" />
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>

        <group targetFramework="net46">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.1"/>
            <dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" />
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>
        <group targetFramework="net47">
            <dependency id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.1"/>
            <dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" />
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1"/>
        </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

and package your own nuget file and use it in your project. https://programmium.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/keen-io-windows-phone-8-1-and-nuget-package-creation/ this post will tell you how to create a new nuget package.

Comment: But the point is that I don't want "Microsoft.Net.Http". But I already went and added net47 to the frameworks and web-push-csharp won't *compile* without that reference. What leads me to my question: **why**. I have `System.Net.Http` in 4.7 already.

Comment: Its because you said in the nuspec file. If you want to use `System.Net.Http` alter the `<dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" />` as `<dependency id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" />` But this is not recommended as the nuget package is created for `Microsoft.Net.Http` not for `System.Net.Http`. If you really really want to use `System.Net.Http` just rewrite the entire thing with the removal of `Microsoft.Net.Http` and introduce  `System.Net.Http`

Comment: But why would I need a nuget package at all, for something that in my target is an automatic reference when I say "Create new project"?

Comment: If you already have the dependency referenced (with the correct version) in your project it will be totally fine, else it will be downloaded.

Comment: Further more System.Net does not have an implementation for `Http` ref - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx you need to reference the https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/ to the .csproj file you've mentioned in your question

Comment: I'm talking about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx, which seems to be a part of .NET 4.5, 4.6 and 4.7... and I wonder why I would need a nuget package for that.